# Repeating XML elements using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I've got to create an XML document which has to have the same information repeated in different parts. I'm creating some `details` as an etree.Element and trying to append it to a couple of secondary XML elements

```py
from lxml import etree

top = etree.Element('Primary')
element1 = etree.Element('Secondary')
element2 = etree.Element('Secondary')

details = etree.Element('Details', somevalue='value')

element1.append(details)
element2.append(details)
top.append(element1)
top.append(element2)

print(etree.tostring(top, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True))
```

The output I want is;

```xml
<Primary>
  <Secondary>
    <Details somevalue="value"/>
  </Secondary>
  <Secondary>
    <Details somevalue="value"/>
  </Secondary>
</Primary>
```

The output I get is;

```xml
<Primary>
  <Secondary/>
  <Secondary>
    <Details somevalue="value"/>
  </Secondary>
</Primary>
```

lxml seems to treat the `details` element only being allowed in one place. Is there any way to turn this off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The following is extracted from the [lxml documentation](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html)

> Note that in the original ElementTree, a single Element object can sit
>   in any number of places in any number of trees, which allows for the
>   same copy operation as with lists. The obvious drawback is that
>   modifications to such an Element will apply to all places where it
>   appears in a tree, which may or may not be intended.
>
> The upside of this difference is that an Element in lxml.etree always
>   has exactly one parent, which can be queried through the getparent()
>   method. This is not supported in the original ElementTree.

So an element in lxml can only have one parent unlike the original element from ElementTree. So its not possible to just append the same element to more than one parent using lxml. However the documentation suggests to handle this new design you should use deep copy to copy the element you want to append to another element if its already assigned somewhere.

This will create a new copy of the element and as such the new copy can be assigned to a different parent element. These are seperate copy's so changing one will not change the other.

```
from lxml import etree
from copy import deepcopy

top = etree.Element('Primary')
element1 = etree.Element('Secondary')
element2 = etree.Element('Secondary')
details = etree.Element('Details', somevalue='value')
element1.append(details)
element2.append(deepcopy(details))
top.append(element1)
top.append(element2)
print(etree.tostring(top, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<Primary>
  <Secondary>
    <Details somevalue="value"/>
  </Secondary>
  <Secondary>
    <Details somevalue="value"/>
  </Secondary>
</Primary>
```

**Updated with example for Jack**

So in thie example Jack i set a variable `num_secondarys` that will create X secondary elements each with a details element and the values in the detail element will incrmement by 1. I create a single element of secondary and detail as a template, then use deepcopy to copy them as new elements.

```
from lxml import etree
from copy import deepcopy

top = etree.Element('Primary')
secondary = etree.Element('Secondary')
detail = etree.Element('Details', somevalue='value')
num_secondarys = 3
for i in range(1, num_secondarys + 1):
    this_secondary = deepcopy(secondary)
    this_detail = deepcopy(detail)
    this_detail.attrib['somevalue']+=str(i)
    this_secondary.append(this_detail)
    top.append(this_secondary)

print(etree.tostring(top, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<Primary>
  <Secondary>
    <Details somevalue="value1"/>
  </Secondary>
  <Secondary>
    <Details somevalue="value2"/>
  </Secondary>
  <Secondary>
    <Details somevalue="value3"/>
  </Secondary>
</Primary>
```

Comment: Very elegant! Our of curiosity (and if it's not too much work!) - how would the answer change if in the first `Details` the `somevalue` attribute had `value_1` as  value, but the second had it as `value_2`?

Comment: @jack fleeting I am not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle - the expected output has two identical `<Details somevalue="value"/>` tags, one inside each of the two `<Secondary>` parent tags.  I'm trying to figure out how the code would change if the desired output was for  `<Details somevalue="value one"/>` inside the first `<Secondary>` tag but `<Details somevalue="value two"/>` inside the other.

Comment: After adding teh deep copy to element 2 you can just modify the attribute value `element2[0].attrib['somevalue']='valueTwo'`

Comment: Alternatively you could just make a deep copy of details as details2 `details2 = deepcopy(details)` and then modify its value `details2.attrib['somevalue']='valueTwo'` then allocate this object to element2 `element2.append(details2)`

Comment: @JackFleeting I added an update in my answer showing a solution that adds X number of secondary elements ith incrementing details value

Comment: @ChrisDoyle - I wish I could upvote the answer twice :)

Answer (score 0):

Below (using ElementTree the builtin python XML library)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element('Primary')
for x in range(2):
  sec = ET.SubElement(root, 'Secondary')
  details = ET.Element('Details')
  details.attrib['somevalue'] = 'value'
  sec.append(details)
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<Primary>
   <Secondary>
      <Details somevalue="value" />
   </Secondary>
   <Secondary>
      <Details somevalue="value" />
   </Secondary>
</Primary>
```